# Piping functions in Scala (merging map and andThen)

Tags: scala

Piping things in Scala is often very simple - think `map` for collections, `compose`and `andThen` for [function composition](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/pattern-matching-and-functional-composition.html).

However, I don't seem to find a way to combine the two. I have a function that returns an `Option[Double]`. I'd like to filter the `Double` value (reduce its precision) if it's there. `andThen` is close but needs me to handle the option thingy.

Is there a nice built-in way to deal with this in Scala 2.11?

```
class Temp( ff: (Object) => Option[Double] )

object Temp {

  def apply( f: (Object) => Option[Double] ) = {

    def cutTo5Digits(v: Double): Double = {
      v - (v % 1e-5)
    }

    // call 'f', then pipe its output (if some) via 'cutTo5Digits'?
    //
    //new Temp( f map cutTo5Digits )    // nope
    //new Temp( f _ andThen cutTo5Digits _ )   // would need option unwrapping

    new Temp((o: Object) => f(o) map ((v: Double) => cutTo5Digits(v)))  // compiles
  }
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with `new Temp(f(_) map cutTo5Digits)`?

Comment: Nothing - was suggested in your answer and I marked it as approved. I did not know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the best solution would be `new Temp(f(_) map cutTo5Digits)`, what's wrong with it?

But if you want syntax like this: `f map cutTo5Digits`, then you can use Kleisli from scalaz, where `f` would be of type `Kleisli[Option, Object, Double]`, i.e:

```
def apply( f: (Object) => Option[Double] ) = {
    def cutTo5Digits(v: Double): Double = v - (v % 1e-5)
    val ff = Kleisli(f)
    new Temp(ff map cutTo5Digits) // or inline Kleisli(f) map ...
  }
```

Or you can also make `cutTo5Digits` of type `Double => Option[Double]`, such functions can be chained with Kliesli `>=>` method and you case can be rewritten as `ff >=> cutTo5Digits`.

Comment: The 'f(_)' is awesome, thanks! It may not be immediately obvious to the reader that it's a function composition, but this is what I was trying to reach. I may add a comment in there.

Comment: @akauppi this is not a composition, you are applying `f` and map over the result. Composition would be in case of Kleisli, where you chain monadic functions and then apply the chain.

Comment: Thanks for the correction of terms, @4lex1v. I'm using Scala for real, but exposure to theories and terminology of functional programming is still vague. We are many, I believe.. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `andThen` syntax, you can lift your function into a functor, for instance like this:

```
def liftOption[A, B](f: A => B): Option[A] => Option[B] = _.map(f(_))
```

To highlight the function composition, you can now write:

```
(f _) andThen liftOption(cutTo5Digits _)
```

If you make this conversion implicit, you can even use your original `f _ andThen cutTo5Digits _`. If you are using Scalaz, you should be able to lift your function via `cutTo5Digits.lift[Option]`.